# Django Test Client Method Override Header

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, put, x-http-method-override

I am trying to test my update method on my viewset. The viewset is a modelviewset taken from drf. To update i would need to send a put request. As this is not always supported there are 2 ways to tell the server i am making a put request, the first which does not fit my needs is to use an additional field to form called `_method` and set it to `put`. As i need to post json data i need to use the second way, which uses the `X-HTTP-Method-Override` header.

To post my data in the testcase i use the following code:

```
header = {'X_HTTP_METHOD_OVERRIDE': 'PUT'}
response = client.post('/model/1/', content_type='application/json', data=post_data_clean, **header)
```

But unfortunately the result I get is `{'detail':'Method POST not allowed.'}`. I tested the behavior of the server using a addon ([Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop)) where i specified the `X-HTTP-Method-Override` header too. No exception is raised. I need to know now how to correctly pass the header to the django test client, otherwise testing will get really annoying over here.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

You need to specify header as `'HTTP_X_HTTP_METHOD_OVERRIDE'` instead of `'X_HTTP_METHOD_OVERRIDE'` i.e. add `HTTP_` at the beginning of the header.

```
header = {'HTTP_X_HTTP_METHOD_OVERRIDE': 'PUT'}
response = client.post('/model/1/', content_type='application/json', data=post_data_clean, **header)
```

From the [Django documentation:](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META)

> HTTP headers in the request are converted to `META` keys by converting
>   all characters to uppercase, replacing any hyphens with underscores
>   and **adding an `HTTP_` prefix to the name**. So, for example, a header
>   called `X-Bender` would be mapped to the `META` key `HTTP_X_BENDER`.

Comment: Why the eff is this so hard to find in the documentation!?

Comment: @KeatsKelleher - Bigger question is why is this what the behavior is? Anyways, I had basically the same issue trying to use a cookie in my test - to pass a cookie, I needed to do `header = {'HTTP_COOKIE': 'position=44.4444,-77.7777'}`

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare it turns out the behavior of the test client is documented (or hinted at, rather), https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/testing/tools/#making-requests

Comment: @miraculixx - Not really... it mentions `HTTP_HOST` and `HTTP_ACCEPT` but other than that all it does is say that names follow the CGI convention. It doesn't elaborate on what that is, but it does include a link to some CGI docs which start of by saying the docs aren't maintained and that the links are broken.

Answer (score 12):

Also, you can pass headers to the constructor of the Client:

```
from django.test import Client

client = Client(HTTP_USER_AGENT="Mozilla/5.0 ...", HTTP_X_USER_ID="982734")
```

This way every request will contain default headers.

**PS**: This approach is valid for DRF TestApiClient and ApiRequestFactory.

Answer (score -1):

Django 4.2 offers a `headers` keyword argument.  See the [Django 4.2 release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/releases/4.2/#tests):

> The RequestFactory, AsyncRequestFactory, Client, and AsyncClient classes now support the headers parameter, which accepts a dictionary of header names and values. This allows a more natural syntax for declaring headers.
>
> ```py
> # Before:
> self.client.get("/home/", HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE="fr")
> await self.async_client.get("/home/", ACCEPT_LANGUAGE="fr")
>
> # After:
> self.client.get("/home/", headers={"accept-language": "fr"})
> await self.async_client.get("/home/", headers={"accept-language": "fr"})
> ```